# Is the <clipPath> just a bad alternative to <mask>?

Tags: html, xml, svg, mask, clipping

### SVG Clipping vs. Masking

I recently came across **clipping and masking** in SVG. I noticed that the [`<mask>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/mask) element includes every feature of the [`<clipPath>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/SVG/Element/clipPath) element.

In addition, `<clipPath>` has many disadvantages:

- lower [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/SVG/Element/clipPath#Browser_compatibility)
- no transparency allowed
- no structural, gradient or image elements allowed

Because of this I wonder what the `<clipPath>` element is for:
The `<mask>` element is much more powerful!

---

That is my **code**:

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="100" height="100">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clip">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="50" height="50"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="grey" clip-path="url(#clip)"/>
</svg>
```

---

### Finally, my questions:

- Should I use `<mask>` instead of `<clipPath>` in my code snippet?
- Is there any situation when `<clipPath>` is more suitable than `<mask>`?

Comment: Mask is raster, clip-path is vector. Usually a clip-path will be much much faster providing it's suitable at all as an alternative.

Comment: @RobertLongson Is <mask> a raster element even if you don’t use any image??

Comment: Yes. From the spec: "Note that SVG ‘path’s, shapes (e.g., ‘circle’) and ‘text’ are all treated as four-channel RGBA images for the purposes of masking operations."

Comment: @RobertLongson Thank you! You could use this as answer of my quesion.

Answer (score 1):

Mask is gradual, while clip-path clearly defines the area in the sense what is there and what not. This means that clip-path gives a clickable area, while mask does not change the click are at all, meaning that also the areas that are masked away can be clicked.

Comment: Good point! The unchanged pointer area when applying a `<mask>` is an important aspect. You could improve your answer by adding an example illustrating the different behaviors.