# Problem with CSS SVG Clip path - not working

Tags: css, google-chrome, clip-path

I have a problem with a clip path css. When I put clip path on my css fill, image wont show... I m on chrome. So you have any idea ?

I use this generator https://10015.io/tools/svg-blob-generator

```
.card .content .picture img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius:50%;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px 2px #fff;
    clip-path: path('M317.5,327.5Q297,415,179.5,392.5Q62,370,103.5,270.5Q145,171,210,151.5Q275,132,306.5,186Q338,240,317.5,327.5Z');
}
```

Comment: The svg paths itself appears valid so can you show more of your code for context?

Comment: Most likely your image is too small or your clip-path too large. The problem with clip-path defined by css path() method: they won't be responsive. See also this post [cc-tricks: Unfortunately, clip-path: path() is Still a No-Go](https://css-tricks.com/unfortunately-clip-path-path-is-still-a-no-go/). The alternative would be using an [inlined svg clip-path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28311741/responsive-clip-path-with-inline-svg#answer-28312070).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an easy workaround you might also use [`mask-image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask-image):

1. Copy the complete mask/blob svg (including the parent svg with viewBox attribute).
2. Convert the svg to a data-url [(e.g. via Yoksel's URL-encoder for SVG
   )](https://yoksel.github.io/url-encoder)

#### Example 1: css mask-image (mask svg inlined as data url)

```css
svg {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10em;
}

.picture {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 500px;
  height: auto;
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  resize: horizontal;
  overflow: auto;
}

.imgMask {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  mask-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 480 480' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' %3E%3Cpath fill='%23474bff' d='M465.5,291Q452,342,416,379Q380,416,335.5,439Q291,462,239.5,464Q188,466,144,440.5Q100,415,62.5,379Q25,343,13.5,291.5Q2,240,16,189.5Q30,139,61.5,97.5Q93,56,141,36Q189,16,239,20.5Q289,25,334,45.5Q379,66,412,103.5Q445,141,462,190.5Q479,240,465.5,291Z' /%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  -webkit-mask-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 480 480' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' %3E%3Cpath fill='%23474bff' d='M465.5,291Q452,342,416,379Q380,416,335.5,439Q291,462,239.5,464Q188,466,144,440.5Q100,415,62.5,379Q25,343,13.5,291.5Q2,240,16,189.5Q30,139,61.5,97.5Q93,56,141,36Q189,16,239,20.5Q289,25,334,45.5Q379,66,412,103.5Q445,141,462,190.5Q479,240,465.5,291Z' /%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;
  mask-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-mask-size: contain;
  mask-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="picture">
  <img class="imgMask" src="https://placekitten.com/g/300/300" alt="" />
</div>
```

Unfortunately you will need some vendor-prefixes (e.g. `-webkit-mask-image`) to provide the best compatibility.
Those required prefixed properties can also "bloat" your css file size (albeit negligible when using rather lightweight svg code or just a few mask-images).

#### Example 2: using clip-path:

```css
.picture {
  height: auto;
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
}

.resize{
  width: 500px;
  resize: horizontal;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.img{
  aspect-ratio:1/1;
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.imgClip {
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  -webkit-clip-path: url(#my-clip-path);
  clip-path: url(#my-clip-path);
}

.clipPath{
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden
}
```

```html
<h3>Clip-path </h3>
<div class="resize">
  <img class="img imgClip " src="https://placekitten.com/g/300/300" alt="" />
</div>
<!--hidden clip path svg-->
<svg class="clipPath">
  <!-- scale path to fit a 1x1 viewBox: 1/480 = 0.002 -->
  <clipPath id="my-clip-path" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox" transform="scale(0.002 0.002)"><path fill="#474bff" d="M465.5,291Q452,342,416,379Q380,416,335.5,439Q291,462,239.5,464Q188,466,144,440.5Q100,415,62.5,379Q25,343,13.5,291.5Q2,240,16,189.5Q30,139,61.5,97.5Q93,56,141,36Q189,16,239,20.5Q289,25,334,45.5Q379,66,412,103.5Q445,141,462,190.5Q479,240,465.5,291Z" />
  </clipPath>
</svg>
```

#### Example 3: mask vs. clip-path

As pointed out  here ["Is the  just a bad alternative to ?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50631162/is-the-clippath-just-a-bad-alternative-to-mask/76027929#76027929)  there are still significant differences:

- `<mask>`supports semi-transparent areas
- `<mask>` is usually less performant (compared to `<clipPath>`) since

> Note that SVG ‘path’s, shapes (e.g., ‘circle’) and ‘text’ are all
> treated as four-channel RGBA images for the purposes of masking
> operations.

[14.4.2.1. Calculating mask values](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-SVG2-20120828/masking.html#MaskValues)

- unlike `<clipPath>`, `<mask>` won't change/clip an element's **hit area for pointer events**

```css
svg {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10em;
}

.picture {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 500px;
  height: auto;
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  resize: horizontal;
  overflow: auto;
}

.imgMask {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  mask-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 480 480' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' %3E%3Cpath fill='%23474bff' d='M465.5,291Q452,342,416,379Q380,416,335.5,439Q291,462,239.5,464Q188,466,144,440.5Q100,415,62.5,379Q25,343,13.5,291.5Q2,240,16,189.5Q30,139,61.5,97.5Q93,56,141,36Q189,16,239,20.5Q289,25,334,45.5Q379,66,412,103.5Q445,141,462,190.5Q479,240,465.5,291Z' /%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  -webkit-mask-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 480 480' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' %3E%3Cpath fill='%23474bff' d='M465.5,291Q452,342,416,379Q380,416,335.5,439Q291,462,239.5,464Q188,466,144,440.5Q100,415,62.5,379Q25,343,13.5,291.5Q2,240,16,189.5Q30,139,61.5,97.5Q93,56,141,36Q189,16,239,20.5Q289,25,334,45.5Q379,66,412,103.5Q445,141,462,190.5Q479,240,465.5,291Z' /%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;
  mask-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-mask-size: contain;
  mask-size: contain;
}


.imgClip:hover,
.imgMask:hover{
background:red;
  opacity:0.5;
}

.picture {
  height: auto;
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
}

.resize{
  width: 500px;
  resize: horizontal;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.img{
  aspect-ratio:1/1;
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.imgClip {
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  -webkit-clip-path: url(#my-clip-path);
  clip-path: url(#my-clip-path);
}

.clipPath{
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden
}
```

```html
<h1>Pointer areas: mask vs. clip</h1>
<h2>Masked image still has an unchanged rectangular hit area</h2>
<div class="picture">
  <img class="imgMask" src="https://placekitten.com/g/300/300" alt="" />
</div>

<h3>Clip-path </h3>
<div class="resize">
  <img class="img imgClip " src="https://placekitten.com/g/300/300" alt="" />
</div>
<!--hidden clip path svg-->
<svg class="clipPath">
  <!-- scale path to fit a 1x1 viewBox: 1/480 = 0.002 -->
  <clipPath id="my-clip-path" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox" transform="scale(0.002 0.002)"><path fill="#474bff" d="M465.5,291Q452,342,416,379Q380,416,335.5,439Q291,462,239.5,464Q188,466,144,440.5Q100,415,62.5,379Q25,343,13.5,291.5Q2,240,16,189.5Q30,139,61.5,97.5Q93,56,141,36Q189,16,239,20.5Q289,25,334,45.5Q379,66,412,103.5Q445,141,462,190.5Q479,240,465.5,291Z" />
  </clipPath>
</svg>
```

#### Further reading: About clip-path caveats and pitfalls

[Eric Meyer: Scaling SVG Clipping Paths for CSS Use](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2017/02/24/scaling-svg-clipping-paths-for-css-use)
[Css-tricks: Unfortunately, clip-path: path() is Still a No-Go](https://css-tricks.com/unfortunately-clip-path-path-is-still-a-no-go)
[Css-tricks: Clipping and Masking in CSS](https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/)

#### Clip path helper

[Convert SVG absolute clip-path to relative](https://yoksel.github.io/relative-clip-path)