# CSS relative clip-path: path() not working (entire bg image not showing), where is the code issue?

Tags: css, svg, mask, clip-path, image-masking

I am building a hero element that I'm trying to make each 'piece' link to a different page, and since there is a lot of overlapping have opted for clip-path instead of masking. Here is an image showing what I'm trying to accomplish, and below is the relevant code:

[hero element visual, showing each piece of the element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aiEvo.png)

HTML & CSS: (#htl1 = top left-most element in visual, #htl2 = 2nd top left-most element, same deal for the rest of the pieces)

```
<style>
    #hero {
        position: relative;
        display: block;
        height: 58vw;
    }

    #htl1 {
        width: 29vw;
        height: 29vw;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        background: url(htl1.jpg) no-repeat center center;
        background-size: cover;
        clip-path: path("M0,0 V1 L1,0 H0");
        z-index: 2;
        position: absolute;
    }

    #htl2 {
        width: 50vw;
        height: 35vw;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        background: url(htl2.jpg) no-repeat center center;
        background-size: cover;
        clip-path: path("M0,0.837 V1 H1 V0 H0.6 L0,0.837");
        z-index: 1;
        position: absolute;
    }
</style>

<section id="hero">
    <a href="#1" id="htl1" class="masked"></a>
    <a href="#2" id="htl2" class="masked"></a>
    <a href="#3" id="htr1" class="masked"></a>
    <a href="#4" id="htr2" class="masked"></a>
    <a href="#5" id="hbr1" class="masked"></a>
    <a href="#6" id="hbr2" class="masked"></a>
    <a href="#7" id="hbl1" class="masked"></a>
    <a href="#8" id="hbl2" class="masked"></a>
</section>
```

I've tried getting this to work a number of ways but something about how this clip-path process works is eluding me. At this point I'm wondering if this is even possible, but I may simply be missing something basic here as I'm relatively new to working with SVGs in this fashion (masking/clipping).

I used this relative clip-path converting tool to turn them from userSpaceOnUse to objectBoundingBox, as this needs to be responsive and always span the full width of the page: https://yoksel.github.io/relative-clip-path/

Previously, when it was set to an absolute clip-path (e.g. based on viewbox I think?) it did clip the image, but the sizing was wrong. I've also tried this with various clipPath implementations inside an SVG file, but didn't have any success their either. A CSS only solution (e.g. path is all within the clip-path property) would be ideal to keep things simple.

Thank you for your time & consideration.

added example:

```css
#hero {
        position: relative;
        display: block;
        height: 58vw;
    }

    #htl1 {
        width: 29vw;
        height: 29vw;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        background: url(https://placehold.co/100) no-repeat center center;
        background-size: cover;
        clip-path: path("M0,0 V1 L1,0 H0");
        z-index: 2;
        position: absolute;
    }

    #htl2 {
        width: 50vw;
        height: 35vw;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        background: url(https://placehold.co/100) no-repeat center center;
        background-size: cover;
        clip-path: path("M0,0.837 V1 H1 V0 H0.6 L0,0.837");
        z-index: 1;
        position: absolute;
    }
```

```html
<section id="hero">
    <a href="#1" id="htl1"></a>
    <a href="#2" id="htl2"></a>
</section>
```

Comment: I found another svg path conversion tool, and this is spitting out slightly different results than the other one... this may be part of the problem? not sure https://lea.verou.me/blog/2019/05/utility-convert-svg-path-to-all-relative-or-all-absolute-commands/

Comment: Please add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Your current code doesn't render anything.

Comment: @herrstrietzel added. This is just the first 2 elements (top left and 2nd top left) from the reference image. You'll notice nothing visibly renders, but that is the problem I'm having/question I have.

Comment: You're using a CSS clip-path, those will always be in userSpaceOnUse units so you'll need to convert back or swap to an SVG clip-path

Comment: Dang that completely kills my current plan then. I was hoping to keep the path data all in the CSS file. That's unfortunate, will have to revisit the SVG clipPath option then. I may not have tried it with the converted path data. If I get this working I will answer my own question, but if anyone has any suggestions or insight in the meantime, maybe there is another workaround... Thank you for the note @RobertLongson on CSS being only userSpaceOnUse, I had no idea.

Comment: Have a look at this SO post ["Problem with CSS SVG Clip path - not working"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71286372/problem-with-css-svg-clip-path-not-working/71299443#71299443)